# Text validation - Textarea

Tags: html, angularjs

I wanna validate text area text.

In cases empty, html text empty like

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
</table>
```

All empty cases should not accept. Please suggest js/angularjs code

Here is my textarea

```
<textarea placeholder="Answer" ng-model="answer"></textarea>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. Do you want to validate that a string of HTML has at least some visible content or text in it, or?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen yes you are correct it should be having atleast one visible  text.

Comment: What about other visible content? Does an `<img>` count as visible content? How about text that isn't going to be visible? Does `<template>Hi</template>` count at visible? This isn't as simple as you might think.

Comment: when you validate the textarea on button click or ready

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen My requirement is any visible content after ng-bind-html should not consider as empty

Comment: @JqueryKing on button click

Answer (score 1):

Take it as idea not an answer

Use **ng-show** directive

```
    <textarea placeholder="Answer" ng-model="answer" ng-show="isValidate"></textarea>

<button ng-click="validate()">Submit</button>
```

in contrller

```
function ctrl($scope){
  $scope.isValidate = true;
  $scope.validate = function() {

     if($scope.answer.length === 0){
          $scope.isValidate = false;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a directive that matches your `td` tags and sees if they have content or not

```
.directive('td', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
     link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
       if (elem[0].textContent === '') {
         // handle validation
       }
     }
  }
});
```

You can also check against `elem[0].innerHTML` if the content inside the `td` should be HTML and not plain text. And if you don't want to match all `td` tags you can just make a custom name for your directive and assign it an all tags where this is needed

Comment: How to assign all tags?

Comment: The snippet above already assigned this directive to all ```td``` tags